# Difference between Debian's linux-image-cloud-amd64 and linux-image-amd64

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, cloud

I understand that the "cloud" kernel images are optimized for use in IaaS environments, but what exactly are the differences from the regular kernel images?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cloud images are built without support for features which are unnecessary in cloud environments: most hardware drivers are disabled, support for the x32 ABI is disabled, as are microcode updates, machine check exceptions etc.

You can see all the differences by comparing [the base cloud configuration](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux/-/blob/master/debian/config/config.cloud) to [the base non-cloud configuration](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux/-/blob/master/debian/config/config), and [the `amd64` cloud configuration](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux/-/blob/master/debian/config/amd64/config.cloud-amd64) to [the `amd64` non-cloud configuration](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux/-/blob/master/debian/config/amd64/config).